# What does the code FU1FU2FU5 mean in this metar?

Tags: weather, metar, canada

In their METAR, CYPK reported `... 25SM FEW037 SCT050 OVC250 21/15 A3016 RMK FU1FU2FU5 DENSITY ALT 400FT`.

Since it's quite smokey out, I would have expected a simple `FU` in the weather section after visibility.

I'm wondering what `FU1FU2FU5` is about. According to the remark format at http://meteocentre.com/doc/metar.html it should be "layer type and opacity in oktas". Is this just the way to say "sky covered by smoke"?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's indeed the layer type and [okta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Okta), but in the remark the layer type is **repeated** for each reported cloud (smoke) layer. From your example:

```
FEW037  →  FU1
SCT050  →  FU2  →  1+2=3
OVC250  →  FU5  →  3+5=8
```

The oktas of the layers are added, that's how OVC is shown as 5 and not 8, by adding the previous oktas it does become 8.

```
FEW = 1 to 2
SCT = 3 to 4
BKN = 5 to 7
OVC = 8
```

Similarly for CYCD:

```
METAR CYCD 012200Z 34010KT 12SM BKN038 BKN051 30/11 A3012
RMK FU5FU2 VIS LWR N-E SLP201 DENSITY ALT 1600FT=

BKN038  →  FU5
BKN051  →  FU2
```

When no remark is needed for the smoke (French: Fumée), the FU code is placed before the remark:

```
METAR CYBD 012200Z 29007KT 8SM FU FEW240 28/13 A3019
RMK CC1 SLP225 DENSITY ALT 1400FT=
```

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/METAR#North_American_METAR_codes), this is how Canada handles the remark section. Here is what [navcanada.ca](https://www.navcanada.ca/en/Media/Publications/AWS-Guide-EN.pdf) says:

> Where observed, the obscuration and cloud type amount **for each
>   reported layer** is included in remarks. It may exceed 8 oktas if a higher
>   layer is observed through transparencies in a lower layer

(Emphasis mine.)